# Limit number of fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, find

I have the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "TkwLvyzp77BXiY4RW",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T00:21:17.213Z"),
    "title" : "Test",
    "lines" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "497bd9e27cfec6da261a809d",
            "text" : "Bla bla bla 1"
        }, 
        {
             "id" : "fd2b8a805d9dc2c4e6269c69",
             "text" : "Bla bla bla 2"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "fd3f6f4ca1360d69dcfe61a1",
            "text" : "Bla bla bla 3"
        }, 
        ....
        ....
        {
            "id" : "7b6e4103f880ce8dd9935000",
            "text" : "Bla bla bla N"
        }
    }
},
{ ... },
{ ... }
```

I need to find documents from the collection and limit number of "lines". 
Trying like "Articles.find({ lines: { limit: 5 } }), but it is not right.

Comment: What about this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/ ?

Comment: Use [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Comment: I do not need to limit number of documents, but number of "lines" in the found documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$slice is the best option.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

`db.Articles.find({},{"lines": { $slice: 5 }})`